# ggplot geom_point varying size with windows size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got some issue creating a map with `ggplot2` above which I project points using `geom_point`. When exporting in pdf or in an other support, the point size varies (because she's absolute and not axis-relative). I've searched how to change that and found a lot of answers saying, that it was on purpose, because if it wasn't the case it would be changing to ellipse each time the axis proprtions change. I understand that, however, because I work on a map, I use `coord_fixed` to fix the output and avoid distorsions of my map, so if I was able to fix the point size relatively to the plot size, it wouldn't be a problem.

Is there some solution to do that? I've read some interesting things suggesting using `geom_polygon` to artificially create ellipses. But I have two problems with this method:

- First I don't know how to implement that with my data, now I know the place where the centers of my points are, but how could I then later say how to define all the centers and then defin a filled circled polygon around?
- Second I have used `scale_size_continuous` to plot smaller or bigger points relatively to other variable. How could I implement that with `geom_polygon`?

Facit: I would be happy either with the possibility of override the impossibility to determine a relative unit for the point size, or with some help to make me understand how I can create the same thing with the function `geom_polygon`.

I tried to join a small reproducible example here. It is only an example, the problem with my data is that I have a lot of closed small values (mainly 1, like the small dot in the reproducible example), and so they seem really good, but when exporting it can become very bigger and create a lot of problems by overplotting, which is the reason why I need to fix this ratio.

[Link for the map informations](http://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo-vd.ortschaftenverzeichnis_plz/PLZO_CSV_LV03.zip) and [second link for map informations](http://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo-vd.ortschaftenverzeichnis_plz/PLZO_SHP_LV03.zip)

```
dat <- data.frame(postcode=c(3012, 2000, 1669, 4054, 6558), n=c(1, 20, 40, 60, 80))

ch <- read.csv("location/PLZO_CSV_LV03/PLZO_CSV_LV03.csv", sep=";")#first link, to attribute a geographical location for each postcode
ch <- ch%>%
  distinct(PLZ, .keep_all=TRUE)%>%
  group_by(PLZ, N, E)%>%
  summarise
ch <- ch%>%
  filter(PLZ %in% dat$postcode)
ch <- ch%>%
  arrange(desc(as.numeric(PLZ)))
dat <- dat%>%
  arrange(desc(as.numeric(postcode)))
datmap <- bind_cols(dat, ch)

ch2 <- readOGR("location/PLZO_SHP_LV03/PLZO_PLZ.shp")#second link, to make the shape of the country
ch2 <- fortify(ch2)

a <- ggplot()+
geom_polygon(dat=ch2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), colour="grey75", fill="grey75")+
geom_jitter(data=datmap, aes(x=E, y=N, group=FALSE, size=n), color=c("red"))+ #here I put geom_jitter, but geom_point is fine too
scale_size_continuous(range=c(0.7, 5))+
coord_fixed()
print(a)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ggsave()` to save the last plot and adjust the scaling factor used for points/lines etc. Try this:

```
ggplot(data = ch2) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
               colour="grey85", fill="grey90") +
  geom_point(data=datmap, aes(x=E, y=N, group=FALSE, size=n),
             color=c("red"), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(0.7, 5)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_void()

ggsave(filename = 'plot.pdf', scale = 2, width = 3, height = 3)
```

Play around with the `scale` parameter (and optionally the width and height) until you are happy with the result.

DO NOT use `geom_jitter()`: this will add random XY variation to your points. To deal with overplotting you can try adding transparency - I added an `alpha` parameter for this. I also used `theme_void()` to get rid of axes and background.

Your shape file with map information is quite heavy: you can try a simple one with Swiss cantons, like [this one](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a5067fb3b0b74b188d7b650fa5c64b39).[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already use theme_void, I just let it on the side because I wanted to give a minimal example, and thanks for the cantons idea, in fact I use another far more complicated graph to plot the swiss shape with lakes and mountains, but just used this one as an example. But I'll probably need some canton plot later in my work, so thanks, I'll take a look! Thanks for the alpha tip too. I use R Sweave, so the better option is to save the plot and then add it to in the LaTeX environment using `\includegraphics` if I understand good? It seems to work so, so thank you very much!

Comment: ggsave is ideal if just want to create a standalone file with your plot. If you are instead planning to embed the figure in a document using Sweave or knitr, you could also try adjusting the point size using the theme option, e.g. `theme_void(base_size = 10)`